# Org mode - change code block background color

Tags: org-mode, coloring

I wish to change the code block background color in org mode but below example doesn't work.

```
#+ATTR_HTML: :background-color #eff0f1;
#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE
hello world!
#+END_EXAMPLE
```

Can I insert inline css code with #+ATT_HTML

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can do what you want with `#+ATTR_HTML`. However, your HTML is incorrect. If you look at the output you will see `<pre class="example" background-color="#eff0f1;">` but there is no background-color attribute in HTML. Instead, use this:

```
#+ATTR_HTML: :style background-color:#eff0f1;
#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE
hello world!
#+END_EXAMPLE
```

This will generate `<pre class="example" style="background-color:#eff0f1;">`, which will apply color to that block only.

Comment: Thanks.  Seems to only be applicable to `example` or `verse` block.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
#+HTML_HEAD: <style type="text/css">.example {background-color: #eff0f1; color: #ff0000;}</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution works for everything block. Is it possible to add a attribute only apply to current code block? then I can apply different color for different block.

Comment: How could the same be achieved for a pdf document using LaTeX?